# Can you create a Google Group, group contact that includes members and NON members?

Tags: google-groups

Ideally we would like our building management to email on topics involving them.  I do NOT want them as a member of our building owners group as they are not owners and sometimes topics are sensitive to only owners.

Answer (score 1):

From Google Groups you could create a new topic and add CC. You could use CC to include the email address of those that are not members of the group.